# Merged terms and renamed and it doesn't work

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, term-store, merge

In an on-premise SharePoint 2013 Farm, I merged two terms and renamed the remaining term. When I do a search on the User Profile Field for the new term, I get no results. I ran the crawl.

What do I need to do to get the new term working?

Comment: Not sure about 2013, but in SP2010 there is a timer job called "Taxonomy Update Scheduler" that needs to be run in order to push changes in the Term Store out to the sites that use those terms.

Comment: That's a good idea but that runs every two minutes and seems to not solve the problem.